# <h:input> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to implement jsf + primefaces + twitter bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
>
<h:head>
    <title>IMPORT JSF SET ATTRIBUTES</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/override.css" />

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
-->
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner navbar-large">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="brand" href="#">Name</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#buy">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                    <div class="input-append offset1">
                        <h:input class="span5" placeholder="put search terms here"
                            type="text" />
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">
                            <i class="icon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> How to <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="nav-header">Link</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Link</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#register">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">[Template content will be inserted here]</div>

    <footer>
    <ul class="inline text-center">
        <li>© 2013</li>
    </ul>
    </footer>
    <!--/.fluid-container-->

    <!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.js" />

</h:body>
</html>
```

However, I get:

```
<h:input> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: input
```

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: My maven project has `<jsf-version>2.1.3_01</jsf-version>`

Comment: `h:input` tag doesn't exist in JSF.

Comment: In which JSF book/tutorial/resource did you learn about `<h:input>`? Or was this just randomly guessed? Why exactly did you expect it would work? In any way, bookmark the tag documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ Further I'd also use a decent IDE with decent JSF plugins. Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ would already have warned about an unknown tag and also have shown a list of autocomplete suggestions while entering.

Comment: You've by the way other issues in your template. IE conditional comments and HTML5 attributes in JSF components won't work this way, but this is subject for different questions (which are already several times asked before here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`h:input` tag doesn't exist in JSF. Use some of specific input tags, for example: `h:inputHidden`, `h:inputText`, `h:inputSecret`, `h:inputTextarea`.

Comment: I see this tag using in Lynda course. The Eclipse doesn't show the error. But, I check with `CTRL+Space` that it doesn't pop up the tag. alternative tag is <h:inputText></h:inputText>

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, are you sure you mean h:input and not h:inputtext?

sorry -> edit: you are doing the follwing:

```
          <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                <div class="input-append offset1">
                    <h:input class="span5" placeholder="put search terms here"
                        type="text" />
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">
                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and thats plain html, won't work with JSF
if you wanna use the magic of JSF you must do something like that:

```
            <h:form>
                    <h:inputText value="#{hereIsYourManagedBean.field}" />
                    <h:commandButton action="#{hereIsYourManagedbean.action}">
                         DoJsfAction
                    </h:commandButton >

            </h:form>
```

The JSF-Servlet will catch your action, render the input form, put it in your ManagedBean fields, call the method of the ManagedBean and finally create a response, depending on your method. Mostly another xhtml-site which is configured by your faces-config.xml

Comment: Please rewrite your answer. Currently, it looks like a comment and even insults OP (and future readers).

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to develop in JSF 1.2 and I wasn't completely sure, if there maybe exist such a component in JSF 2.0/2.1

Comment: The problem with your answer is in the first line: *Silly question*. With that sentence, even if the rest of the body is right, your answer is offensive.

Comment: If you can't answer an question, it's better to just refrain from answering. Stack Overflow is not like a cluttered discussion forum where you can post guesses/shoot-in-the-darks as "answers" (replies). Here, comments should be used for that (note that you can only post comments on someone else's posts when having at least 50 reputation, so start posting good answers first ;) )

Comment: By the way, `<h:input>` doesn't exist in JSF :) (maybe you want to edit that too).

Comment: I didt't wanny say, that maximus asked a silly question. I just wanted to suggest that he should use one of the known h:input* components. But I admit that it can be misunderstand :)